# How to set different email address to private Stack Overflow for teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

My Stack Exchange public account has my private email.
I have created a private team (free Stack Overflow for teams) and I would like to use my work email for that.
I couldn't find how to do that.

Is that possible?